# Function that receives 2 possibles parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function that serves to create users, but I have defined two models "users" and "demo users" so I have two different models.

The models have similar and different properties, but for example they have properties such as "email" that are common.

The function has this structure, I receive as a parameter an object "User" but I would like you to receive an object "User" or an object "DemoUser"

```
public function createLogin(User $user)
{
...
}
```

I do not know if this would be the subject of injecting dependencies ...

Thank you and I await your comments

Comment: why are you not using the built-in authentication in laravel? `php artisan make:auth` will generate the auth system for you.

Comment: Does one of your models extend the other? eg "Demo Users" extend "Users" ?

Answer (score 2):

Solely on the question of allowing the method to accept both User and DemoUser types, you can setup an Interface class that both User and DemoUser may implement.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do can be achieved using interfaces or abstract classes. Create an interface and implement it in the two models or create an abstract class and extend it from your two users class. Then when passing the argument, use the interface or the abstract class as the type hint e.g

```
public function createLogin(UserInterface $user) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

```
public function createLogin($user)
{
    if (is_a($user, 'App\User')) 
    {
       // Create your user here     
    } 
    elseif(is_a($user, 'App\DemoUser'))
    {
     // create demo user here   
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not sound good. What if there are many more subinstances?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you. But the asker said "I would like you to receive an object "User" or an object "DemoUser"."

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways is to extend the class that has the `createLogin` method, and rewrite that method with:

```
public function createLogin($user)
{
    if ($user instanceOf User) {
        parent::createLogin($user)
    }
    if ($user instanceOf DemoUser) {
        // Login logic for DemoUser
    }
}
```

*Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Why not use inheritance? Why should a `createLogin` method know about single instances of a user?

Comment: @NicoHaase I suppose that's another way of doing it. Add that answer for the asker please.

Comment: There is no need to duplicate the answer of LC Yoong while the OP does not share more information